# Neo4j Error - NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.neo4j.internal.helpers.Exceptions

Tags: java, neo4j

I moved my working project from my current PC to another PC.
I'm using an embedded Neo4j and I am trying to print the Nodes with JUNG.
On my old PC it works fine, but now I have a problem with embedded Neo4j.

The following is an example of one of my functions. This function checks if a node with the specified name (passed in as the `node` parameter) exists. If not, the function tries to correct typos, and tries to find the node again.
Neo4j has at the moment a problem with the function **managementService.shutdown()**.
I checked the project setup from both PCs. The setups should be the same.
I hope some one can help me fix this.

#### Function

```
public String is_Node_in_DB(String node) {
        boolean nodeexists = true;
        int retcnt = 0;
        
        Node n1 = null;

        String db_path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "./Hagen_NLPToolbox_March2021/Hagen_NLPToolbox_March2021/cooccsdatabase";
        java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(db_path);
        if(Files.exists(path))
        {
            File database = new File(db_path);

            managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(database).build();
            graphDB = managementService.database(DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME);

            System.out.println("database opened for querying");

            try (Transaction tx2 = graphDB.beginTx()) {     
            
                do {
                    n1 = tx2.findNode(Labels.SINGLE_NODE, "name", node);
                    if(n1 != null)
                    {// if node found break bevor improvements starts
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(retcnt ==2)
                    {
                        node = node.toUpperCase();
                    }
                    else if((retcnt == 2)&&(n1 == null))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(Character.isUpperCase(node.charAt(0)))
                    { // check of typo lower letter improvements 
                        node = node.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + node.substring(1);
                        retcnt = retcnt+1;

                    }
                    else if(Character.isLowerCase(node.charAt(0)))  
                    { // check of typo upper letter improvements
                        node = node.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + node.substring(1);
                        retcnt = retcnt+1;
                    }
                }while(n1 == null);
            
                tx2.commit(); // success();
            }
            managementService.shutdown();
        }
        else
        {
            node = "";
        }
        return node;
    }
```

#### Log (with exception)

```
JRE Eclipse Adoptium/17.0.5 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled.
 Eclipse debugger will use less precise source lookup implementation for this debug session, but everything else will continue to work otherwise.
Upgrading Eclipse to the latest version will likely make this warning go away.java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Users\+user+\eclipse-workspace-2\DB-Suche\Dokto.json (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Dokto/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.10/logback-classic-1.2.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Dokto/eclipse-workspace-2/DB-Suche/Neo4jDB/Neo4jDB/lib/tika-app-1.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Dokto/eclipse-workspace-2/DB-Suche/Neo4jDB/Neo4jDB/Neo4jLibs/slf4j-nop-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Dokto/eclipse-workspace-2/DB-Suche/Neo4jDB/Neo4jDB/JUNGLibs/slf4j.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Processing took 0 seconds.
16:08:07.640 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
16:08:07.646 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG reactor.core.publisher.Hooks - Hooking new default : onErrorDropped
16:08:08.944 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
16:08:08.946 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
16:08:08.946 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
16:08:08.965 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
16:08:08.965 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 17
16:08:08.966 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
16:08:08.967 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
16:08:08.967 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
16:08:08.968 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
16:08:08.968 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
16:08:08.969 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
16:08:08.970 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @660fd534
16:08:08.970 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
16:08:08.970 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
16:08:08.971 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 2097152000 bytes (maybe)
16:08:08.971 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\Dokto\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
16:08:08.971 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
16:08:08.971 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
16:08:08.972 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
16:08:08.972 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
16:08:08.973 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
16:08:08.973 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
16:08:08.973 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 16
16:08:08.973 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 16
16:08:08.973 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 9
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 4194304
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: false
16:08:08.974 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
16:08:08.979 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.u.i.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
16:08:08.979 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG i.n.u.i.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
database opened for querying
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.neo4j.internal.helpers.Exceptions
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:188)
    at org.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.shutdown(DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.java:131)
    at core.Cooccs.is_Node_in_DB(Cooccs.java:2949)
    at main.DBPlot.check_User_Input(DBPlot.java:1554)
    at main.DBPlot.add_Cluster_to_Graph(DBPlot.java:1752)
    at main.DBPlot.actionPerformed(DBPlot.java:274)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:525)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:740)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:856)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1810)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2947)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2995)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2909)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6403)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1952)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:883)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1150)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1020)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4882)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
emphasized text
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.neo4j.internal.helpers.Exceptions  - do you have everything installed here?

Comment: Hi @Fermi-4, sorry for the delay. But do you mean with installed ??

Comment: This issue is either you don't have the dependency jars present on your system or they are not on the classpath of the jar.. That is why you see error `Could not initialize class org.neo4j.internal.helpers.Exceptions`. How is your project setup?

Comment: Hi @Fermi-4, i have a multimodule project.  One child project is the embedded Neo4j DB. The parent project will bundle the embedded Neo4j project with another child project. In this case JUNG. Do you want to see the pom file ??

Comment: Sure I think that would be good to add..

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks like an issue with the classpath/project setup... It looks like there was some manual installation process for the child project i.e.:

`<systemPath>${basedir}\Neo4jLibs\neo4j-data-collector-4.1.3.jar</systemPath>`

Have you repeated whatever necessary steps to put these dependencies into the `${basedir}\Neo4jLibs` path on the new machine?

Comment: Hi, i reworked the maven issues. At the moment, i can see the child project is using mentioned neo4j jar files.  But now i got the same error 
Could not initialize class org.neo4j.internal.helpers.Exceptions
I know the version neo4j Version is a bit old, 4.1.3. Has this neo4j 4.1.3 a special dependencie to an special JDK Version ??